# Ideal $(f,g)$ in $R[x]$

Tags: polynomials

Let $R$ be a UFD (so $R[x]$ is as well).

Given $f, g \in R[x]$ coprime  with $\deg(f), \deg(g) \geq 1$ and $a \in (f,g) \cap R$, can one always find $u,v \in R[x]$ with $\deg(u) < \deg(g)$ and $\deg(v) < \deg(f)$ such that $a = uf + vg$?

Comment: It is certainly not true if $f,g \in R$.

Comment: Also, $a$ has degree $0$, so all higher degree terms in $uf+vg$ would have to cancel...which is weird.

Comment: @Plop: True. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** $\: $ If $\rm\ a = u\:f + v\:g\:,\ f,g\:$ monic, the  Division Algorithm $\rm\:\Rightarrow\ u = b\:g + \bar u,\ v = c\:f + \bar v\ $ with $\rm\:deg\ \bar u < deg\ g\ $ and $\rm\: deg\ \bar v < deg\ f\:.$

Google **reduced resultant** for literature on this topic.

Comment: Thanks.  This does the trick.

Comment: Of course, if $f$ and $g$ are not monic, it's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be the integers, and try $f(x)=2x+5$, $g(x)=2x+1$, $a=1$.

Comment: Is $a \in (f,g)$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$